# Error while reading XLSX files with python - Bad magic number for central directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsx

**Purpose**

1. Downloading .xlsx file from AWS S3 to local directory
2. Reading downloaded .xlsx file as a pandas Dataframe

**Pre-information**

- macOS, Windows, linux give same error
- Python 3.9 and 3.8 used
- Tried methods:

  - pd.read_excel(path_, engine=None, header=0, index_col=0)
  - pd.read_excel(path_, engine='openpyxl', header=0, index_col=0)
  - xlrd.open_workbook()
  - z = ZipFile()

**Error Traceback**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1352, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory
```

**Error Line**

```
centdir = fp.read(sizeCentralDir)
        if len(centdir) != sizeCentralDir:
            raise BadZipFile("Truncated central directory")
        centdir = struct.unpack(structCentralDir, centdir)
        if centdir[_CD_SIGNATURE] != stringCentralDir:
            raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")
```

**Library Versions**

- pandas==1.4.3
- xlrd==2.0.1
- openpyxl==3.0.10

Comment: could be a problem with the version of zip. Not sure about python - but java for example does not have native deflate64 support  and can't open some files compressed by windows exlorer, You could try https://pypi.org/project/zipfile-deflate64/

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 service not working well with excel files. I think the file structure may be corrupted after upload to S3. In order to upload and process Excel files, I started storing them by converting them to parquet or csv files.

**Update: Storing files into new HDFS - Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when working with a Google Drive integration on my macOS. The solution for me was to download all files to local disk in Finder before running the script - rather than working from online-only copies.

Comment: Hey Michael, Actually we are downloading files from S3 before processing with pandas. But i believe S3 not optimal for XLSX files.